# Best way to change a users password with AWS Cognito Hosted UI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-cognito

We use AWS Cognito with the Host UI for login and signup.

We require a user to be able to change their password.

There is an auth flow state in Cognito called `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. When the user is in this state, upon successful login via Hosted UI, the user is then instructed to change their password before they continue.

The issue is that we cant find a way to force a users state to be `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`. We are instead having to use AWS API to change a password.

We chose the Hosted UI option because we wanted to offload auth responsibility from our app. Having to use the AWS API to change a password means we are now pulling in 'auth stuff' into our stack (auth forms, val, api services, testing, ongoing maintenance) which we want to avoid/minimise.

Is there some way to set the users state to `FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD`? As this would keep everything in the Hosted UI, and solve our problem.

We were hoping to find an api method like `adminSetUserState`??

Comment: It's important that cognito manages some of its own internal state to make sure developers don't accidently compromise the security of the user pool. Just use `AdminSetUserPassword` to set the password to a cryptographically secure random string and you've accomplished the same thing...

Comment: In that case create a lambda+apigw endpoint that will do it for you.

Comment: I can write one out for you if you aren't grasping it.

Comment: @AndrewGillis thats ok thanks - i dont think your solution will work if it relies on a random string to be generated. The Hosted UI requires user to login first before redirecting to change password screen (unless ive misunderstood the flow)

Comment: Oh I misunderstood your intention. The flow then would be to hijack the reset password mechanism.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminResetUserPassword.html

Comment: @AndrewGillis my use case is not a password reset, its for a user to change their password either by choice, or because they reached a 'change password' time period. We dont want to implement this via api if there is a better way and have the cognito hosted API do it

Comment: Think more 'change password' not 'reset password'. A reset would require extra validation via email etc - thats not our use case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232294/discussion-between-gaz-edge-and-andrew-gillis).

Answer (score 0):

The closest method for offloading the user's own password change function to AWS is to allow the user to initiate the process [ChangePassword](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html) directly.

Example Javascript

```js
const changePassword = async ({
  currentPassword,
  newPassword,
  region,
  accessToken
}) => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch(`https://cognito-idp.${region}.amazonaws.com`, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
        "X-Amz-Target": "AWSCognitoIdentityProviderService.ChangePassword",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "AccessToken": accessToken,
        "PreviousPassword": currentPassword,
        "ProposedPassword": newPassword,
      }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(json.message);
    }
    
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
};
```

This process require `AccessToken` which user already have when login.
It also require `aws.cognito.signin.user.admin` on OpenID Connect scopes.